# How to interpret threshold value not intersecting with smooth in ordered GAM?

Tags: interpretation, ordinal-data, generalized-additive-model

My model consists of an ordered factor with four levels as the response variable and a continuous predictor.

```
mod <- gam(lev ~ s(pred), family = ocat(R = 4))
```

The smooth of the predictor looks like this:

[image]

The estimated threshold values are:

```
> mod$family$getTheta(TRUE)
[1] -1.00000000  0.09669527  1.27291819
```

However, the last value (1.27) does not intersect with the smooth. How can that be interpreted?

---

### Edit to include reproducible example:

---

(taken from https://github.com/eric-pedersen/mgcv-esa-workshop/blob/master/example-forest-health.Rmd)

```
library(mgcv)

forest <- read.table(url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eric-pedersen/mgcv-esa-workshop/master/data/forest-health/beech.raw"),
                     header = TRUE)

forest <- transform(forest, id = factor(formatC(id, width = 2, flag = "0")))

## Aggregate defoliation & convert categorical vars to factors
levs <- c("low","med","high")
forest <- transform(forest,
                    aggDefol = as.numeric(cut(defol, breaks = c(-1,10,45,101),
                                              labels = levs)),
                    watermoisture = factor(watermoisture),
                    alkali = factor(alkali),
                    humus = cut(humus, breaks = c(-0.5, 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5),
                                labels = 1:4),
                    type = factor(type),
                    fert = factor(fert))
forest <- droplevels(na.omit(forest))

ctrl <- gam.control(nthreads = 3)
forest.m1 <- gam(aggDefol ~ s(age),
                 data = forest, 
                 family = ocat(R = 3), 
                 method = "REML",
                 control = ctrl)
summary(forest.m1)

plot.gam(forest.m1, shift = coef(forest.m1)[1])
```

The plot has been shifted by the intercept of -1.72, theta values are -1 and 2.38, so the latter value is far above the range of the smooth.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't have to intersect with the smooth - you're not including the model constant term when trying to interpret the result.

There is an underlying latent variable stretching from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ and the cut points $\theta_r$ ($r \in {1,\dots,R}$) mark the transitions from one category to the next where there are $R+1$ categories. The value of the linear predictor $\hat{\eta}_i$ for an observation, yields a value (point) on this latent variable. Together, the $\hat{\eta}_i$ and $\theta_r$ determine the estimated probability that the $i$th observation falls in each category.

The linear predictor in this model is of the form

$$
\eta_i = \alpha + f(x_i)
$$

where $\alpha$ is the model constant term (the thing labelled `(Intercept)` in the output from `summary()` `coef()` etc.)

To reconcile your observation that the partial effect of the smooth term $f(x_i)$ never gets above +1, we might conclude that the constant term $\alpha$ is a positive value sufficient to produce values of the linear predictor that are greater than 1.27 to allow the model to predict the $R+1$th category.

The y axis here is not the latent variable or the value of the linear predictor; it's the partial effect of the smooth $f(\mathbf{x)}$, which has been subjected to an sum-to-zero identifiable constraint, which has the effect of centring the smooth about the model constant term. All you can really conclude from the plot of the partial effect of $f(\mathbf{x})$ is that as you increase the value of $x_i$, the probability that you'll fall into one of the higher categories increases, for $x_i \approx 50$, and between  $50 \lessapprox x_i \lessapprox 100$ the effect of increasing $x_i$ is also to increase this probability but the effect on $Y$ for a unit change in $x_i$ is lessened and for $x_i \gtrapprox 100$ there is little effect of $x$ on the response. But this all needs to be recentred about the estimated value for $\alpha$ if you want to show the linear predictor (and that is only possible visually here as your model has a single smooth).

#### Notes on the reproducible example

The apparent contradiction (or confusion) in the Forest example from our course, is due to `age` not being a great predictor of `aggDefol`, and especially it cannot distinguish very well at all categories 2 and 3:

```r
library("ggplot2")
library("gratia")
library("tibble")

ggplot(forest, aes(x = age, y = aggDefol)) + 
  geom_point()
```

[image]

If you look at the estimated probability of category conditional upon `age`, we also see the issue:

```r
ds <- data_slice(forest.m1, age = evenly(age))
fv <- fitted_values(forest.m1, data = ds)

fv |>
  ggplot(aes(x = age, y = fitted, colour = category, group = category)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper, fill = category, colour = NULL),
              alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

And this is reflected in the cut point for the 3rd category being outside the range of the values on the latent variable that are predictable given the smooth of `age` (the model)

```r
p <- ds |>
  add_column(latent = predict(forest.m1, newdata = ds))

p |>
  ggplot(aes(x = age, y = latent)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_hline(data = tibble(cuts = gratia:::theta(forest.m1)),
             aes(yintercept = cuts))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation. Yes, I had misunderstood how to interpret the effect of the smooth, much clearer now!!

Comment: I have now revised the plot but the intercept is in fact negative (-1.4), so that now there are even less intersections. I am surely missing something else? It would be great if you could give a me hint.

Comment: It would help if you could provide a reproducible example - I don't work with these models that much so I don't have a simple example lying around that matches what you are seeing. If you can construct one or use/modify the example in `?ocat` and point out what you see is an issue, and **add it to your original question** I'll try to take a look

Comment: Thanks, I've added an example based on data from your course, hope that's ok.

Comment: I am still struggling with this problem and you are my only hope.. Any chance you have a minute to look into this? I'd highly appreciate, thanks!

Comment: @erc for specific examples you need to look into the data to understand what is going on. Plot `age` against `aggDefol` and hopefully you see the issue (hint, `age` is not a good predictor on it's own of `aggDefol` and especially of the 3rd category

Comment: Got it now, thanks so much!